# Confusion about Python Decode method

Tags: python, decode, encode

I'm trying to run the command `u'\xe1'.decode("utf-8")` in python and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why does it say I'm trying to decode ascii when I'm passing utf-8 as the first argument? In addition to this, is there any way I can get the character `á` from `u'\xe1'` and save it in a string?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The python script I'm running takes text, processes it, and prints a JSON string containing a categorized version of the original text. What I've noticed is that characters like this sometimes end up as their unicode values in the printed JSON string.

Comment: when you print your string you will see `á`

Comment: So I was able to solve the problem. Thank you guys for the help. But I'm still confused on why the error says it's an `ascii` encoding problem when I'm using `utf-8` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`decode` will take a string and convert it to unicode (eg: `"\xb0".decode("utf8")  ==> u"\xb0"`)

`encode` will take unicode and convert it to a string (eg: `u"\xb0".encode("utf8")  ==> "\xb0"`)

neither has much to do with the rendering of a string... it is mostly an internal representation

try

```
print u"\xe1"
```

(your terminal will need to support unicode (idle will work ... dos terminal not so much))

```
>>> print u"\xe1"
á
>>> print repr(u"\xe1".encode("utf8"))
'\xc3\xa1'
>>> print repr("\xc3\xa1".decode("utf8"))
u'\xe1'
```

Comment: hey can we do this too??. >>> chr(ord("\xe1"))
'á'

Comment: The rule given in the answer is mostly true for 2.x, perhaps always for 3.x.  The example output is for 2.x, slightly different in 3.x.

Comment: in python 2 it is `>>> unichr(ord("\xe1")) 'á'` @Hackaholic